# how to convert value to hex to send in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to put a value in an array of hex, to write in a device via modbus/TCP through socket.
My problem is that I can't get the `hex` value with the type like the elements of `byteArrayWriteTemperature`. 
Then I calculate the `crc` to prepare the array to send and I need to append this `crc` in the last two elements of the array

so for example for a `value = 45` my array would be:

```
array = [0x01, 0x10, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x2d, 0x23, 0x8d]
```

With the `Crc16()` method if `buff = [0x01, 0x10, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x2d]`
where the last element is `0x2d` which in decimal is `45`, I get the crc `swapped = 8d23` instead of `238d` like the last 2 elements of `array`

```
setTemperature(value: number) {
    console.log('about to set temperature value ', value);
    let hex = value.toString(16)

    const byteArrayWriteTemperature = [0x01, 0x10, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, hex];
    let crc = this.Crc16(byteArrayWriteTemperature, byteArrayWriteTemperature.length)
    console.log('crc ', crc)
    console.log('array: ', byteArrayWriteTemperature);
    this.writeToDevice(byteArrayWriteTemperature)
  }

Crc16(buff, length) {
    let crc = 0xffff;

    for (let pos = 0; pos < length; pos++) {
      crc ^= buff[pos]; // (uint8_t)          // XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc

      for (let i = 8; i != 0; i--) {
        // Loop over each bit
        if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {
          // If the LSB is set
          crc >>= 1; // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
          crc ^= 0xa001;
        } else {
          crc >>= 1; // Just shift right
        } // Else LSB is not set
      }
    }
    return crc;
  }
```

How can I prepare my array correctly?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I am understanding the question correctly, you want your crc stored in little endian order and appended to the end of the array.

So the where you have:

```
return crc;
```

You need to do:

```
return [crc & 0xFF, (crc & 0xFF00) >> 8];
```

Which would return an array containing [0x23, 0x8d]; assuming the value of crc was 0x8d23

The line after:

```
let crc = this.Crc16(byteArrayWriteTemperature, byteArrayWriteTemperature.length);
```

Add:

```
byteArrayWriteTemperature = byteArrayWriteTemperature.concat(crc);
```

To append the crc to the end of the byteArrayWriteTemperature array